WP delete media array ID on deleting post
Someone have a sample snippet to delete media ID on deleting post?
i have upload metafield that contain array ID of media file attached to post and i wish to delete media files also on deleting post and avoid to have pending/useless media loaded.
thanks

You would be using the delete_post hook, which fires right before a post gets deleted (so you still have access to it). Inside your function, which then fires, you'd fetch all attachments (or attachment IDs) and remove them using wp_delete_attachment.
add_action( 'delete_post', 'delete_attachments_with_posts', 10, 2 );
function delete_attachments_with_posts( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        $attachments = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'post_parent' => $post_id
        ) );
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, true );
        }
    }
}

References: Hook Function

i'd solved
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'wps_remove_attachment_with_post', 10 );
function wps_remove_attachment_with_post( $post_id ) {

global $post;
$post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    if ( $post_type == '<post_type_slug>') {
        
        $gallery = array();
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, '<cpt_metafield>', true );
        $gallery = explode( ',', $meta );
        
        foreach ( $gallery as $img_id ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $img_id );
            wp_delete_attachment( $img_id, true );
        }
   }
}


While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.
